# Creating a database dump doesn't seem to be working

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgresQL 9.6.2 installed, and I'm trying to make a backup of one of my databases (`my_database`) using `pg_dump` command. It doesn't seem to be working as I see no output file.
I'm using a Mac and from my terminal (and in my project directory) I use:

```
psql postgres postgres
pg_dump my_database > my_database.bak
```

being `postgres` my database default user and password.
I've already tried using `sudo psql postgres postgres` with the same results.
I imagine that I'm experiencing some kind of lack of permissions but cannot understand it.
So, how to have the right permissions to do this?

Comment: It looks like you might be using `pg_dump` from inside the postgres command line? It's a shell command, not a postgres command.

Comment: If you properly end every statement inside psql with `;` you will see the error.

Comment: ok, I was doing it from the postgres command line. But now I'm getting error when using my passwords. Is there a better (more complete) command than `pg_dump my_database > my_database.bak`?

Comment: @ jmelesky Ok, I think I got it using: `pg_dump -U postgres my_database > my_database.bak`. Could you please make an answer so that I can accept it (the main issue was really that I was running the command from my postgres command line...

Comment: I wonder if PostgreSQL should add detection of attempts to run `pg_dump`, `pg_restore`, `sudo`, etc on the `psql` command line? We already do so for `PGDMP` to help confused people trying to run `psql -f some_custom_format_dump_file`. Probably not; it's not unreasonable to expect someone to try semicolon-terminating it like all other psql commands and then they'll get a useful error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres comes with a bunch of stuff, including command-line tools. That includes the standard client, `psql`, and also the command `pg_dump`. That needs to be invoked from a shell command line.

If you type it into a `psql` command line, you'll get a syntax error once you terminate the line (with a '`;`') -- it's not valid sql, nor a valid command to `psql`.

Hope that helps!